# Compute the inverse of a matrix with partially known values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an odd problem. I have a matrix $A$ of size 16 per 16. As an example, we will consider the 4 by 4 matrix below.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}50 & 3 & 10 & 2\\\ 3 & 60 & 7 & 1\\\ 10 & 7 & 55 & 4\\\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 45 \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find the matrix $B$ such as:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} & 0\\\ b_{21} & b_{22} & 0 & 0\\\ b_{31} & 0 & b_{33} & b_{34}\\\ 0 & 0 & b_{43} & b_{44} \end{pmatrix}$$
where I forced some of the values $b_{ij}$ to $0$ and where $C = B^{-1}$ such that $C_{ij}$ is equal to (or as close as possible) to $A_{ij}$ if $B_{ij} \neq 0$.

In other words, if I inverse the matrix $B$, I want to get the same values as $A$ where in the position $(i, j)$ $B$ is not set to $0$.

Additionally, the matrix $A$ and the matrix $B$ are symmetric. Moreover, the diagonal values $A_{ii}$ are about 10 times larger than the off-diagonal values $A_{ij}$.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

*N.B: If anyone has a better title for this post... I'm open to suggestions :)*

Comment: "I have an odd problem." Why is it odd and not even? One can do a direct computation for the inverse of $B$. Do you want to see this? Then one can solve the equations imposed by your condition.

Comment: Actually, I obtain only $7$ equations in the $7$ variables  $b_{ij}$. All equations are easy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I just looked up and "odd" was definitely not the word I intended to use (I'm not a native English speaker...). Sorry ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $7$ equations in $7$ variables $b_{11},b_{12},b_{13},b_{22},b_{23},b_{33},b_{34}$, which have, for example, a solution
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{27497}{1321025} & - \frac{1}{997} & - \frac{1}{265} & 0 \\\
- \frac{1}{997} & \frac{50}{2991} & 0 & 0 \\\
- \frac{1}{265} & 0 & \frac{136093}{7167985} & - \frac{4}{2459} \\\ 
0 & 0 &  - \frac{4}{2459} & \frac{55}{2459}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $B^{-1}$ has the required form. In fact, we have
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} 
50 & 3 & 10 & \frac{8}{11} \\\
3 & 60 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{12}{275} \\\
10 & \frac{3}{5} & 55 & 4 \\\
\frac{8}{11} & \frac{12}{275}  & 4 & 45
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It seems this problem was trivial for you... how do you get the equations linking the element of $B_{i,j}$ to the elements of $A_{i, j}$? That is precisely where I am stuck as I lack the formula linking the element $e_{i, j}$ of a matrix to the element of its inverse.

Comment: The matrix equation $A=B^{-1}$ has $n^2=16$ equations in the coefficients $b_{ij}$ of $B$, because we have a formula for the inverse (in general very ugly, but here quite nice) and can compare each matrix entry on both sides. Then you just drop the equations which are not needed, because of a $0$, and solve them in the $7$ coefficients.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. So the idea is simply to compute the inverse of $B$, and then to make one equation per element. What did you use to compute the inverse of B, especially with the literal $b_{i, j}$ written. As my matrix has a shape of (16, 16), I'd like to avoid hand-writing the inverse.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right to avoid any hand-writing there. Any CAS will do, like mathematica or maple. Since the matrices are symmetric and have some $0$ in it, it might be possible to compute the inverse even for $n=16$.

Comment: I'll give a shot to mathematica, Thanks!

Comment: In one of your comment, you said that the equations were "easy". You can find here my attempt on Mathematica to replicate this example before going full scale (16 per 16): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204050/matrix-equation-solving The equations do not look simple... in fact, I tried solving them with simpy first, and the program ran for an hour before getting to an error... Could you detail a bit which CAS program you used and how you solved the system? Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the first equation (the other six look completely analogous): $- 50b_{11}b_{22}b_{33}b_{44} + 50b_{11}b_{22}b_{34}^2 + 50b_{12}^ 2b_{33}b_{44} - 50b_{12}^ 2b_{34}^2 +50b_{13}^2b_{22}b_{44} + b_{22}b_{33}b_{44} - b_{22}b_{34}^2=0$. I get several solutions in less than a second. Not all lead to an invertible matrix, though. I use the CAS "reduce" and compute a Groebner basis.